# facebook sdk v4.5.0 crash on startup only in Android less than 5.0

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, facebook-sdk-4.0, inflate-exception, facebook-sdk-4.x

The app crash on startup this is the crash log:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.activities.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.test.ui.shimmer.ShimmerTextView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.test.ui.shimmer.ShimmerTextView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2059)
            at com.framework.base.fragment.base.MCFragmentActivity.setContentView(MCFragmentActivity.java:160)
            at com.test.activities.SplashActivity.setOrientation(SplashActivity.java:50)
            at com.test.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2059)
            at com.framework.base.fragment.base.MCFragmentActivity.setContentView(MCFragmentActivity.java:160)
            at com.test.activities.SplashActivity.setOrientation(SplashActivity.java:50)
            at com.test.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.ui.shimmer.ShimmerViewHelper
            at com.test.ui.shimmer.ShimmerTextView.<init>(ShimmerTextView.java:33)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2059)
            at com.framework.base.fragment.base.MCFragmentActivity.setContentView(MCFragmentActivity.java:160)
            at com.test.activities.SplashActivity.setOrientation(SplashActivity.java:50)
            at com.test.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've done the same thing in this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started). It works on Android 5.0 and above. But if I try this under android 5.0 devices, I got this error log above.

In my SplashActivity:

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
     // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
     // especially, if you're using Facebook UI elements.
}
```

In build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
//        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/DP4Java.jar')
    compile files('libs/SecureStorageSDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/UtilitiesSDK.jar')
    compile 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
}
apply from: 'rollo.gradle'
```

In (top-level)app build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

In manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                   android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

EDIT:
I know that there is nothing wrong in my ShimmerTextView. If I remove facebook sdk from build.gradle, I don't get this error log. Everything works like a charm. There is some kind of bug that I could not figure. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Please help me to solve this issue. 
Thanks.

Comment: The problem definitely seems to be in the ShimmerTextView, the class ShimmerTextView cannot be found. Check your layout xml and ensure that the package name and class name are correct/identical in your layout file for pre android 5.0. The problem is the class specified in the xml cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple layout xml, one for >5.0 versions and one for <5.0 versions? Check that the full package name of your custom view is spelled correctly in all xml files. The `"Error inflating class com.test.ui.shimmer.ShimmerTextView"` indicates that the package name is incorrect or incomplete.

EDIT: Actually it seems that the ShimmerViewHelper cannot be found in the init of the ShimmerTextView, is that referenced correctly? `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.ui.shimmer.ShimmerViewHelper`

Comment: No. There is only one layout. This issue is not about ShimmerTextView. If I remove shimmer animation, some other layout gives same error. On the other hand >=5.0 devices works perfectly, no error at all. Other interesting thing is if I remove facebook sdk, this (ShimmerTextView) error does not occur.

Comment: Something triggers `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.ui.shimmer.ShimmerViewHelper` error when I Add Facebook sdk to my build.gradle. It happens under Android lollipop devices. (Kitkat and lower) If I don't use facebook sdk, everything seems fine, no crashes. Maybe Facebook sdk cause this problem but I don't know why.

Comment: That's a weird one. Are you adding any facebook UI elements to that layout?

Comment: No I don't use any facebook ui elements in layout's